# C++ Reference variable scope issue

Tags: c++, scope, destructor

I'm trying to figure out why the destructor of my Tag class is being called

```
map<string, Tag>* TestLoader::loadCompoundTag()
{
    map<string, Tag>* compound = new map<string, Tag>();
    //Create locally scoped variable
    Tag tag;
    string tagName;
    do 
    {
        loadTag(tag, tagName);
            //Copies variable into map
        compound->insert(std::pair<string, Tag>(tagName, tag));
    //Tag destructor is called before debugger breaks on this line
    } while (tag.type != TAG_End);

    return compound;
}

void TestLoader::loadTag( Tag& tag, string& name )
{
    tag.i = 0;
    name = string("Test");
}
```

Could anyone give me any ideas as to why a destructor is being called there? None of the variables have been defined in the loop's scope, one is created outside the loop and the other is created inside a function. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `std::shared_ptr<Tag> tag(new Tag());`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating it dynamically since It's just going to be copied into the map anyway when  I got a little confused as to why the correct value ends up in the map but the destructor gets called before the loop finishes

Comment: Are you sure the destructed `Tag` object is `tag`, rather than the copy of it in `std::pair<string, Tag>(tagName, tag)`?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue, I didn't realize a temporary was being create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to insert into the map you're creating a temporary,

```
std::pair<string, Tag>(tagName, tag)
```

At the end of the full-expression it's destroyed.

You shouldn't worry about that. If necessary it can be avoided by using `emplace`, but, don't worry about it. Rather, worry about the result type of your function:

*why do you need a dynamically allocated map*?

I'm pretty sure that you don't, i.e., that that is evil premature optimization.

I therefore strongly suggest, focus on correctness and let the compiler do its job of optimization, and write …

```
map<string, Tag> TestLoader::loadCompoundTag() const
{
    map<string, Tag> result;
    do 
    {
        Tag tag;
        string tagName;
        loadTag(tag, tagName);
        result->emplace( std::pair<string, Tag>( tagName, tag) );
    } while (tag.type != Tag::end);
    return result;
}
```

Most probably you don't even need to ask your compiler to optimize, in order to get Return Value Optimization here, which means, that the apparently local `result` is constructed in a memory area provided by the caller, so that no copying is done for the function result.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea pair would create a temporary variable, this explains it :) The map pointer is a member of the a union struct which can also contain a char* pointer to a block of data so it was mostly for consistency

Comment: I still had the same problem with emplace, I ended up solving it by using compound->insert(std::pair<string&, Tag&>(tagName, tag));

Answer (score 2):

`Tag tag` goes out of scope when `loadCompoundTag()` returns, and when that happens, the destructor for it is called.